# Why is it that my output numbers do not return the inputs entered?

Tags: c

I realize that my logic statements are not correct at the time, but I'm frustrated with the numbers not matching my inputs. The numbers usually come out as large integers (ex. 4128168, they're never the same for the integer entered). I'm new to programming in general and can't find much of an answer for this error. Any help is appreciated!

```
int num1;
int num2;
int num3;
int largest;
int second;

printf("Enter three numbers and I'll identify the largest and second largest.\n");
scanf_s("%d%d", &num1, &num2);
(largest = num1);
(second = 0);

if (num2 > largest)
    (largest = num2);
else (num2 > second);
(second = num2);

scanf_s("%d", &num3);
(second = num2);
(largest = num3);

if (num3 > largest)
    (largest = num3);
else (second = num3);

printf("The largest number is %d\n", &largest);
printf("The second largest number is %d\n", &second);

return 0;

}
```

Comment: `(largest = num3); if (num3 > largest)` ? Also, why all those parens around your assignment statements?

Comment: And also, `else (num2 > second);` will produce no effect !  Did you mean `if (....) ?

Comment: How does `scanf_s("%d%d"` know when one number ends and the second begins? How could you tell how many numbers you got? How would you change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
printf("The largest number is %d\n", &largest);
printf("The second largest number is %d\n", &second);
```

You are printing the address, print the values:

```
printf("The largest number is %d\n", largest);
printf("The second largest number is %d\n", second);
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all I recommend you first to read all the data and then to find the greatest and the middle number.

For a better code I would recommend you, also, to put all the data in an array and then to sort it. It would allow you to use your program with the desired number of input and output numbers.

Despite that, the solution that you want is the next:

-You should write:

```
second = num1; //too, initializing

if (num2 > largest)
    largest = num2;
else
    largest = num1;
```

Then the 3rd number.

Instead of:

```
if (num3 > largest) 
    (largest = num3);
else (second = num3);
```

You should write:

```
if (num3 > largest){ //now, comparing the new number with the actual largest
    second = largest; //on this right order without overlapping 'largest'
    largest = num3;
} else if(num3 > second)
    second = num3;
```

Also, you should not write assign statements between parentheses ( ) because it can bring you to confuse conditional statements and assign statements like in your first "else".

Then, it is important to specify your variable names without "&" in your 'printf' calls.

Please, if I helped you, rate me.